# Not Loading Web Component

Tags: vue.js, electron

I am having a very curious issue, out of nowhere yesterday my running app started doing this:
[image]

It IS loading the background.ts file for nodejs, but it is NOT loading anything web side. All of the loaded files are empty.

I went back to a previous release of the app and ran it after clearing out node-modules, and all temp files - but the same thing happened. So the issue does not seem to be my code itself (as this worked previously)

I am using vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder, all packages are up to date. https://pastebin.com/SU1zV7bt

My main.ts:

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(App),
  mounted() {
    // Prevent blank screen in Electron builds
    this.$router.push('/');
  },
}).$mount('#app');
```

It is worth noting I am experiencing this issue on electron 4 and electron 5.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like disabling vue-dev-tools fixed the issue, but I still have no idea why it is suddenly causing problems.